# How to get file contents from absolute path in Node.js in this code?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code in NodeJs,

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.readFileSync('client/assets/images/car-img.jpg');
```

This **client/assets/images/car-img.jpg** is the location of image in system i.e relative path. I want to get file contents **from absolute path like this**. Consider, getting Google image from this absolute path,

```
var data = fs.readFileSync('https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png');
```

How should I read data using **readFileSync**? Any help appreciated.

Comment: `fs` is the **filesystem** module, reads from the local filesystem. You are looking to read from the **Internet** over http. Read the manual here http://nodejs.org/api/http.html or use the request module https://www.npmjs.org/package/request

Comment: oh, thanks a lot. Do you have any sample code to read file over http?

Comment: All right there in the links. `request` is real easy to use

Comment: I am exploring request api you shared.But there seems to be lots of API and I am confused which one to use.

Comment: Doesn't matter; take your pick.